# How do I remove repetitions from multiple JSON files?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have multiple JSON files which contains capitals and countries.How do I remove repetitive key-value pairs from the all the files?

I have one of the following JSON files

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "Capital": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "New Delhi",
        "Country": "India"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Canberra",
        "Country": "Australia"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Beijing.",
        "Country": "China"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Tokyo",
        "Country": "Japan"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Tokyo",
        "Country": "Japan"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Moscow",
        "Country": "Russia"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "New Delhi",
        "Country": "India"
    },
    {
        "Capital": "Ottawa",
        "Country": "Canada"
    }
    ]

}
```

There are many such JSON files containing repetitive items.How do I remove repetitve items keeping only the **first occurence**?I have tried this,but doesn't work

```
dupes = []
for f in json_files:
    with open(f) as json_data:
        nations = json.load(json_data)['data']
        #takes care of duplicates and stores it in dupes
        dupes.append(x for x in nations if x['Capital'] in seen or seen.add(x['Capital']))
        nations = [x for x in nations if x not in dupes] #want to keep the first occurance of the item present in dupes

    with open(f, 'w') as json_data:
        json.dump({'data': nations}, json_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehensions are great! But... they can complicate the code when there is an `if` statement involved along the way.

This is in no way a *rule-of-thumb*. on the contrary, I encourage you to use list comprehensions often. In this particular case a more spread-out solution is more readable.

My suggestion is this:

```
import json

seen = []
result = []

with open('data.json') as json_data:
    nations = json.load(json_data)['data']
    #takes care of duplicates and stores it in dupes
    for item in nations:
        if item['Capital'] not in seen:
            seen.append(item['Capital'])
            result.append(item)

with open('data.no_dup.json', 'w') as json_data:
    json.dump({'data': result}, json_data)
```

Tested and works on Python 3.5.2.

Please note that I have removed your outer loop for my convenience.

Comment: Your code works well for what I hope to achieve.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't use cool list comprehension, but a regular loop should work

```
used_nations = {} 
for nation in nations:
    if nation['Capital'] in used_nations:
        nations.remove(nation)
    else:
        used_nations.add(nation['Capital'])
```

Comment: @nutmeg64 I'm sure someone will make a `python.js` before long ;)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample code of how you can achieve this for your given json

```
import json

files = ['countries.json']

for f in files:
    with open(f,'r') as fp:
        nations = json.load(fp)
    result = [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items())\
            for item in nations['data'])]
print result
print len(result)
```

Output:

```
[{u'Country': u'Russia', u'Capital': u'Moscow'}, {u'Country': u'Japan', u'Capital': u'Tokyo'}, {u'Country': u'Canada', u'Capital': u'Ottawa'}, {u'Country': u'India', u'Capital': u'New Delhi'}, {u'Country': u'Germany', u'Capital': u'Berlin'}, {u'Country': u'Australia', u'Capital': u'Canberra'}, {u'Country': u'China', u'Capital': u'Beijing.'}]
7
```

Comment: Note that this will only filter out duplicate pairs, so `{'Country': 'Russia', 'Capital': 'Moscow'}` and `{'Country': 'Zaire', 'Capital': 'Moscow'}` will both be in `result`